# Sylow tower theorem involving supersolvable groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I just want to find out if anyone has a reference to the result that states that if $G$ is a finite supersolvable group then it has a normal Sylow subgroup.

Comment: It's Exercise 3B.10 in Finite Group Theory by Martin Isaacs. The more precise result is that it has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, where $p$ is the largest prime dividing $|G|$. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831780

Comment: I looked at the proof in the link and decided to attempt to prove it. Firstly, let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of order $q$ where $q$ is a prime and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. I don't see how if $p=q$ then we are done?

Comment: If $p$ is the largest prime dividing $G$ then $p$ is the largest prime dividing $|G/N$. So by induction the Sylow $p$-subgroup, $PN/N\unlhd G/N$ and thus $PN \unlhd G$. By the minimality of $N$ we have that $N=PN$ so $P\leq N$. But $P$  is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ contained in the $p$-subgroup $N$. Thus $N=P$ so $P\unlhd G$. Please check if this is the correct reasoning for the case $q=p$

Comment: $PN=N$ is not correct (in general).

Comment: Oh yes, I seemed to have confused minimal with maximal.