# the order of an automorphism group of a cyclic group and centralization.

Tags: group-theory

From [Supersolvable groups and sylow towers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831780/supersolvable-groups-and-sylow-towers), why does $P$ centralize $N$?

Since $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ is cyclic of order $q-1$, by N/C theorem, $G/C_G(N)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$. Then, for any $g \in P$, its order is coprime to the order of $G/C_G(N)$.... and I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N\trianglelefteq G$ so $P\le N_G(N)$. This means there is an action of $P$ on $N$ by conjugation which defines a group homomorphism $P\to{\rm Aut}(N)$.

Since $p$ divides the order of any non-trivial quotient of $P$ and $|{\rm Aut(n)}|<p$, the image of $P$ must be trivial.

That is $P$ acts trivially on $N$ by conjugation which is the same as saying $P$ centralises $N$.